# how to change some labels in ASP.Net page by for loop form code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 10 `Label` control in an ASP.Net page. their Id are in row like

```
label1, label2, label3, ... ,label10
```

I want to change their `Text` property to something like

```
Home1 , Home2, Home3, ... Home10
```

Can I do this from code behind by using `For` loop or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your labels are inside a `div` tag (don't forget to add `runat="server"`):

```
<div id="labels" runat="server">
  <%--Your Labels--%>
</div>
```

And in the code behind:

```
int i = 1;

foreach (var item in labels.Controls)
{
    if (item is Label)
    {
        ((Label)item).Text = "Home" + i;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: (var item in labels.Controls)  in code behind does not recognize labels.Controls

Comment: Have you Added `runat="server"` to labelss div. tag?